# Chrome print preview

Tags: google-chrome, printing

When printing from Chrome (Version 21.0.1180.82 - OSX) I get an inconvenient print dialog, where chrome tries to take control of the printing away from the OS - is there a way to disable this permanently? I've tried using the suggestions at http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/L8_LF-UCxgU/JtuC1lMUEe4 and http://maketecheasier.com/enable-disable-google-chrome-print-preview/2011/04/13 and didn't get very far... :(

Answer (score 0):

It says what to do right in the Print dialog:

[image]

Either click that link, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to print.

Comment: Apologies - I've edited the question to make it clearer that I'd like to disable the behaviour entirely.